# Subscriber only called once in Rx android and Firebase Realtime-Database Implementation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, rx-android

I am new to android development.
Currently I am implementing Firebase Realtime-Database with Rx android.
Here the Rx Android is used to listen to any changes happened in a particular child node inside the Realtime-Database, retrieve a List of Java class object in it and then return the List so that it can be used by another class.

Below are my code snippets.

1) Here is a class that do basic Database operation such as read, write, update and delete, right now I'm only showing the read operation.

```
public class FirebaseDatabaseLayer {

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase
        .getInstance().getReference();

    private List<TodoComponentFirebase> todoComponentFirebases = new ArrayList<>();

    private FirebaseUser user;

    public Observable<List<TodoComponentFirebase>> readModelFirebase() {

    return Observable.create(new Observable.OnSubscribe<List<TodoComponentFirebase>>() {
        @Override
        public void call(final Subscriber<? super List<TodoComponentFirebase>> subscriber) {
            user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            databaseReference.child(user.getUid())
                .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        for (DataSnapshot todoComponentSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            TodoComponentFirebase todoComponentFirebase = todoComponentSnapshot.getValue(TodoComponentFirebase.class);
                            todoComponentFirebases.add(todoComponentFirebase);
                        }
                        subscriber.onNext(todoComponentFirebases);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                        for (DataSnapshot todoComponentSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            TodoComponentFirebase todoComponentFirebase = todoComponentSnapshot.getValue(TodoComponentFirebase.class);  
                            todoComponentFirebases.add(todoComponentFirebase);
                        }
                        subscriber.onNext(todoComponentFirebases);
                        subscriber.onCompleted();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
             });
        }
    });
}
```

2) Here is class which has a subscriber that listening to the Observable defined in the class in number 1) inside readModelFirebase method

```
public class Presenter {

    private FirebaseDatabaseLayer firebaseDatabaseLayer;

    private Subscription readSubscriber = null;

    public void readFirebaseModel() {
        readSubscriber = firebaseDatabaseLayer
            .readModelFirebase()
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<List<TodoComponentFirebase>>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext (List<TodoComponentFirebase> todoComponentFirebases) {
                    mainView.getFirebaseData(todoComponentFirebases);
                }
            });
    }
}
```

Here the 2) class pass the List of TodoComponentFirebase to the parameter of mainView.getFirebaseData method (I'm not showing concrete implementation of this method here). The idea here is that the mainView.getFirebaseData method will get a List of TodoComponentObject saved in Firebase Database everytime there's change happened in the respective child node.

MainView class is an AppCompatActivity class, the readFirebaseMethod() inside Presenter class is being called in onCreate method of the MainView class, this serve as subscription initialisation.

At the first time initialization of MainView class, the onNext inside readFirebaseModel() is executed, the data being retrieved seamlessly. 
However after that there's no execution on that onNext method even though there's changes occur in Child Node which is defined in the 1) class.

I don't understand why the subscription is not working even though there's changes happen in the child node, it only worked the time it is being initialised. Is there anything missed in my Rx usage ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try remove the

```
subscriber.onCompleted();
```

I think when you call the onCompleted() subscriber will end up and not called again after any child event on firebase.